# Does pep8 allow the usage of \t in a print

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

Is the usage of escaped characters such as `\t` allowed by PEP8 in something like `print` statements?

Is there a more idiomatic way to left indent some of the printout without importing non standard libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's fine, it is a fundamental ASCII character - PEP would not deny its use as it may be fundamental to your end result (say an API needed tabs or something) - PEP is all about styling your source code, I wouldn't consider a character in a string to be something that can be decreed by a style guide (PEP8).

Comment: Sounds about right, but it could have been that some form of pythonic replacement was found that made more sense to use and as such pep8 would be against it.

Comment: No, `\t` translates to a specific character - not just, say, four spaces. It is fundamentally its own character that can be interpreted in its own write so it just wouldn't make sense to outlaw it.

Answer (score 1):

Though there is nothing wrong with using `\t`, you might want to use the `textwrap` module to allow your indented text to be displayed more naturally in your source code. As an alternative to `msg = '\teggs\tmilk\tbread'`, you can write

```
import textwrap

def show_list():
    msg = """\
    eggs
    milk
    bread"""

    print(textwrap.indent(textwrap.dedent(msg), "\t"))
```

Then `show_list()` produces the output

```
        eggs
        milk
        bread
```

When you indent the definition of `msg`, the whitespace is part of the literal. `dedent` removes the *common* leading whitespace from each line of the string. The `indent` method then indents each line with, specifically, a tab character.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong using the tabulator character in a string, at all. See e.g. the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key) for some common usages. You may be confused by [this PEP-8 info](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation):

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

This is similar to [Joe Iddon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61593337/2648551)'s answer. It has to be clear that writing a text (not code, of course) is something different than writing code. Texts and their usages are very inhomogeneous. So setting rules how to format your text does not make any sense (if text is not code).

But you also asked "*Is there a more idiomatic way to left indent some of the printout without importing non standard libraries?*"

Since Python3.6 You can use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to get additional spaces (indentation) in your strings you want to print. (If you're using Python3.5 and lower, you can use the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead, for example.)

The usage is like this:

```py
>>> text = "Hello World"
>>> print(f"\t{text}")
    Hello World
```

This is just a toy example, of course. F-Strings become more useful with more complex strings. If you don't have such complex strings, you can consider also using the arguments of [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) statement like this, for example:

```py
>>> print("Foo", "Bar", "Foo", "Bar", sep="\t\t")  # doubled "\t" only for better displaying
Foo     Bar     Foo     Bar
```

But often it is simply quite enough to include the tab character in your string, e.g.: `"Hello World!\tHow are you doing?\tThat's it."`. As already said, don't do that with code (PEP-8), but in texts it is fine.

If you want to use a module for that (it is a built-in module), I recommend using [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html). See [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61593948/2648551)'s answer for more information how to use that.